# Bottom popup on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I've pretty much finished my website in bootstrap. but now I'm trying to add a bottom popup that either pop on screen after the page has loaded, or after the visitors scroll down a bit. I'd like it to be (almost) exactly as on https://themes.getbootstrap.com/.

I've tried figuring out several examples from bootsnipp and from here, but can not get anything to work. Might be because I have 0 experience with Javascript/jQuery (now even sure where to put the jQuery code), or I'm doing something wrong. Could someone perhaps put me on the right track to creating a similar popup as in the example?

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(document).ready(function(){ /*Your code*/ });` to do something after pageload:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.popup').toggleClass('shown');
  }, 0);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.popup').toggleClass('shown');
  }, 4000);
});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: Open Sans;
}

.popup {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border: 5px solid goldenrod;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  bottom: -200px;
  transition: bottom 1s;
  right: 0;
}

.popup.shown {
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="popup">
  <span>I'm a popup</span>
</div>
```

or use `keyframes` to create popup without js:

```css
* {
  font-family: Open Sans;
}

.popup {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border: 5px solid goldenrod;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  bottom: -200px;
  right: 0;
  animation: popup 5s;
}

@keyframes popup {
  0% {bottom: -200px;}
  20% {bottom: 0;}
  80% {bottom: 0;} 
  100% {bottom: -200px;}
}
```

```html
<div class="popup">
  <span>I'm a popup</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Much appreciated. Now for the noob question: where do I put each snippet?